# How to replace every element in a matrix or raster with the maximum of the values within a variable moving widow of size = n?

Tags: python, raster, r, grass-gis, lidar

So essentially, what I want to do is replace every element in a matrix with the maximum of neighboring cells within a window that is determined by the value in that cell.

The window size would be determined by this function (`fitlwr`), where Tree_Height calls a linear model that was fit to a dataset of Tree Height and Crown Diameter data:

```
RoundOdd <- function(x) {2*floor(x/2)+1} #makes sure window size is an odd number

fitlwr <- function(x){for(i in x){
  if(i > 13){
    m <- RoundOdd(Tree_Heights[Tree_Heights$Tree_Height == i, "fit.lwr"]) 
  return(matrix(1, nrow = m, ncol = m))
    }
  else {
    return(matrix(1, 3, 3))
    }
}}
```

I then want to replace every value in that matrix with the maximum of the values within that window.The matrix was derived from a raster layer and the values represent the height above ground for a given cell. The dimensions are 6,571 x 5,764. A section of the data might look like this:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    9   47  103   58   80   55   72   56   14    52
 [2,]   68   49   49   43   62   80   62   23   55    82
 [3,]   58   10   79   70   75   49   68   60   74    79
 [4,]   78   19   51   26   61   77   57   70   51    43
 [5,]   47   88   57   80   25   33   24   30   56    63
 [6,]   73   36   53   25   63   30   19   59   17    63
 [7,]   95    9   49   95    6   13   21   75   60    34
 [8,]   36   65   47   64   22   66   52    9   71    20
 [9,]   45   53   31   47  114   55   44   42   44    44
[10,]   47   23  102   34   67   60    5   23   61    32
```

The raster focal functions were my go-to, but they don't let you use a variable window size (see below).

```
RoundOdd <- function(x) {2*floor(x/2)+1}

fitlwr <- function(x){
  RoundOdd(Tree_Heights[Tree_Heights$Tree_Height == x, "fit.lwr"]/2)
}

m <- raster::focalWeight(x = CMM, d = fitlwr(), type = "circle")

CMM <- raster::focal(x = CMM, w = m, fun = max)
```

This returns the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(Tree_Heights, Tree_Heights$Tree_Height == x, "fit.lwr") : argument "x" is missing, with no default
6.`[.data.frame`(Tree_Heights, Tree_Heights$Tree_Height == x, "fit.lwr")
5.Tree_Heights[Tree_Heights$Tree_Height == x, "fit.lwr"]
4.RoundOdd(Tree_Heights[Tree_Heights$Tree_Height == x, "fit.lwr"]/2)
3.fitlwr()
2..circular.weight(x, d[1])
1.raster::focalWeight(x = CMM, d = fitlwr(), type = "circle")
```

If I try instead to use the function in the argument for window size, I get this error:

```
Error in .local(x, ...) : is.matrix(w) is not TRUE
5. stop(simpleError(msg, call = if (p <- sys.parent(1L)) sys.call(p)))
4. stopifnot(is.matrix(w))
3. .local(x, ...)
2. raster::focal(x = CMM, w = fitlwr, fun = max)
1. raster::focal(x = CMM, w = fitlwr, fun = max)
```

I am open to using another language or software tools to accomplish this task, including GRASS, Python, QGIS, or ArcGIS if necessary.

Comment: The GRASS module `r.neighbors` calculates pixels values by applying some function to a user defined neighborhood, such as mean, max, min, etc. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Okay! So I think I figured it out:**

**First I convert my raster to a matrix, remove NAs, and round the values (this is unique to my use case and not necessary for the algorithm to function.**

```
X <- raster::as.matrix(Z)
X <- round(X, digits = 0)
X[is.na(X)] <- 0
```

**This is to calculate the maximum for a variable size rectangular moving window:**

```
Y <- X
for (i in 1:nrow(X)){ 
   for (j in 1:ncol(X)){ 
      N <- fitlwr(X[i,j])
      Y[i,j] = max(X[max(1, i-N):min(nrow(X), i+N), max(1, j-N):min(ncol(X), j+N)]) 
  }
}
```

**fitlwr()** is a custom function that calls a linear model that matches the value of a cell to the expected radius of the moving window.

**And here is for a circular moving window:**

```
 Y <- X for (i in 1:nrow(X)){     for (j in 1:ncol(X)){ 
       N = fitlwr(X[i,j])
       M = X[max(1, i-N):min(nrow(X), i+N), max(1, j-N):min(ncol(X), j+N)]
       W = reshape2::melt(M)
       W$d2 = sqrt((W$Var1-mean(W$Var1))^2 + (W$Var2-mean(W$Var2))^2)
       Y[i,j] = max(X[i,j], max(subset(W, d2 <= N, select = value)))}
```

**I then write the values back to my raster**, this maintains the CRS, projection, etc.

```
raster::values(Z) <- Y
```